# cannot read property map of undrfined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

i want to show the data on my app using map function
but it display nothing .
i'm using Redux and MySQL database

i tried to put a default state for (property) it didn't work

this is the component code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator,ScrollView,ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet, Text, View,Button,TextInput,Image} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {gethouse} from '../../store/actions/house_actions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
class Property extends Component {
    static navigationOptions ={
        header:null
    }
    componentDidMount(){
         this.props.dispatch(gethouse());
    }
    postsProperty =(house) =>(
        house.property ?
            house.property.map((item,i)=>(
                <TouchableOpacity key ={i}>
                    <Text>hello</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        ))
        :<ActivityIndicator/>
    )
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style= {{backgroundColor:'#F0F0F0'}}>
                {this.postsProperty(this.props.House)}
            </ScrollView>

      );
    }
}
function mapstatetoprops(state){
    console.log(state);
    return{
        House:state.House
    }
}

export default connect(mapstatetoprops)(Property);
```

and this is the action code

```
import HOUSE_P from '../types';
import axios from 'axios';

export function gethouse(){
    const request =axios({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://192.168.1.4:3000/property'
    }).then(response =>{
        console.log(response.data);
        const property= response.data;
        return property;
    }).catch(e =>{
        console.log(e);
        return false;  
    })
    return{
        type: 'housing',
        payload:request
    }
}
```

this is the reducer

```
import {HOUSE_P} from '../types'
export default function(state={},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case HOUSE_P:
            return {...state,porperty: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

in the debugger i get the data correctly
this is my data
https://i.ibb.co/SdPDsvX/Capture.png

if i comment house.property ? i get this error message
typeError Cannot read property map of undefined
BTW i am displaying the text "hello" just to know if it's working or not it should display hello 3 times as the number of rows in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gethouse` function is doing an asynchronous call using **axios** so your are returning a pending promise as your payload.

I don't know what your reducer looks like so this is a best guess.

You could try making `gethouse` an async function instead:

```
export async function gethouse(){
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method:'GET',
      url:'http://192.168.1.4:3000/property'
    })

    console.log(response.data);
    const property = response.data;

    return {
      type: 'housing',
      payload: property
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;  
  }
}
```

...and then in your component, dispatch the action when `gethouse` resolves:

```
componentDidMount(){
  gethouse()
    .then(action => this.props.dispatch(action));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work :\ . I added the reducer code above if you want , i tried to put this console.warn(house.property) it's showing : undefined

Comment: Should your `mapStateToProps` function return `{ House: state.property }` rather than `{ House: state.House }`?